# sklearn KNN fit throws out error : value too large for dtype('float64')

Tags: scikit-learn, dataset, dataframe, k-nn

I have cleaned the data from nan values and infinite values, the only feature which has a large float is the column 8  (it's a sum)[image: This is what the dataframe look like]

I have no Idea how to fix this last error, I tried all previous solutions which are related to my question but nothing worked.

This is the result of : df.isnull().sum():

[image: isnull]

I am following this tutorial (because I'm just starting to learn about machine learning supervised algorithm KNN):
[Tutorial Link](https://stackabuse.com/k-nearest-neighbors-algorithm-in-python-and-scikit-learn/?fbclid=IwAR2fbH2BuZzeIqomnX2cgH71PVq2vpHsF2MdrTuFVgTXfUBfwPBZE7faNeI)

Please help me out!

Answer (score 1):

You should scale your data before training your data. Try something simple:

```py
df = (df - df.min()) / (df.max() - df.min())
```

If you're using the L2 distance in your knn model this means some values are squared (which is probably why you max out the float64). Btw float64 max is  $2^{31} − 1$ so check the range of the columns just to be sure there might be an outlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost certain that you have missing values, check that and fill them beforehand

Assuming you data frame is called `df`

`df.info()` will give you that info

Additionally `df.describe()` is a good method to validate the maxmimum value is not `np.inf`

Comment: I added the result of df.isnull().sum()

Comment: Does that sum 0 for all the columns?

Comment: Is this a classification task? If so... is you y matrix only binary-valued?

Comment: yes, I updated the question, you can see it on the image

Comment: The dataframe datatypes are: int and float only

Comment: Does your data frame has only numerical (non-object) values?

Comment: yes, all the values are

Comment: Can you share the code for your knn model?

Comment: I will update the question, thanks

Comment: This question might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56894904/how-to-solve-the-error-value-too-large-for-dtypefloat32

Answer (score 0):

Try converting your dataframe to integer values since its `dtype('float64')` is throwing the error. Assuming your dataframe is called df, use this:

```
 df["column_8"] = pd.to_numeric(df["column_8"])
```

This will convert all values in that column to integers.